Changing the dupe target
Long ago I answered this identification question, call it A. Some time later John Rennie answered another question, call it B, which was closed as a duplicate of A. Just now I answered yet another question, call it C, about the same story, "The Last Evolution" by JWC.
Since question C (by Judith Jones) had a remarkably detailed and accurate description of the story, instead of closing it as a duplicate, I closed A as a duplicate of C, in accordance with our policy. But that left B closed as a duplicate of A which was closed as a duplicate of C, and according to our rules there should not be chains of duplicates, so B should be made a duplicate of C.
Question. Am I right, and how should that be done? How do we change B from a duplicate of A to a duplicate of C? Do I have to hail a moderator for that?
What I did was use my gold badge power to reopen B, but then I was unable to close it again.

I do not hold the privilege... but as far as I am aware a gold-badge holder can edit the dupe target list from one to another. It's not an open then close, but an edit. No clue how it's done though! I just know it is possible :P

Note, I've fixed the hanging duplicate; it all looks good now.

Out of curiosity, what made it so you could not close it after re-opening it?

@Clockwork I got a message to the effect that, having retracted my previous VTC, I could not VTC it again.

@user14111 Even gold tag badgers have some limitations on their closing powers :-) But I'm glad this meta post exists and you now know how to edit the duplicates list directly. It's very fortunate that the tag which has the clearest duplication policy (story-ID) is also the tag with the most gold badgers, so you all can use your dupehammer powers freely (according to the policy) and there's almost never going to be a contentious case. Now we just need to get Otis a gold tag badge as well ...

As a gold badge holder in story-identification you can directly edit the duplicates list without opening/closing the question.
Click on the "Edit" button in the upper right corner of the close reason box:

Then use the actions on the next page to add the new (updated) duplicate and remove the existing (old) one:

Once you "Save" this page the duplicate will be updated to the new target without having to open and re-close the post (which can be difficult if you added the story-id tag in the first place).
